# How can I order the Fields of the Custom Settings with Sort() method?

Tags: apex, customsetting, order, sort

This is the method

```
@AuraEnabled
public static list<documentEntity> GetDocumentsInfo(){
    try{
        List<DocumentType__c> documentList = DocumentType__c.getall().values();
        list<documentEntity> result = new list<documentEntity>();
        for (DocumentType__c i : documentList){
            result.add(new documentEntity(i.displayName__c, i.APIName__c, false));
        }
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the constructor of documentEntity

```
public class documentEntity{
    @AuraEnabled
    public String documentName;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String documentAPIName;
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean documentSelected;
    public documentEntity(String documentName, String documentAPIName, Boolean 
    documentSelected){
        this.documentName = documentName;
        this.documentSelected = documentSelected;
        this.documentAPIName = documentAPIName;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that sorting in Apex is rather archaic. You might want to just do sorting on the client instead. It's much faster and easier to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use `list.sort()` with custom types, they must implement [Comparable Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_comparable.htm), that define only one method: `Integer compareTo(Object compareTo)`.

`foo.compareTo(bar)` should return the following values:

- 0 if the objects are equal
- a positive value if `foo` is greater than `bar`
- a negative value if `foo` is less than `bar`

Here's an example that will sort a `List<DocumentEntity>` in ascending order based on the comparison of `documentName`.

```
public class DocumentEntity implements Comparable {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String documentName;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String documentAPIName;
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean documentSelected;

    public documentEntity(String documentName, String documentAPIName, Boolean documentSelected){
        this.documentName = documentName;
        this.documentSelected = documentSelected;
        this.documentAPIName = documentAPIName;
    }

    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        DocumentEntity compareToEntity = (DocumentEntity) compareTo;
        if (documentName == compareToEntity.documentName) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (documentName > compareToEntity.documentName) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Then calling `result.sort()` sort your list.

The comparison can have multiple steps, i.e. if you want to compare first by `documentName`, then by `documentAPIName`:

```
public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
    DocumentEntity compareToEntity = (DocumentEntity) compareTo;
    if (documentName == compareToEntity.documentName) {
        if (documentAPIName == compareToEntity.documentAPIName) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (documentAPIName > compareToEntity.documentAPIName) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    if (documentName > compareToEntity.documentName) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```